How to include C headers without linking libc in Zig
I am attempting to use the Win32 API in Zig without linking libc, since the former does not rely on the latter:
const windows = @cImport({
    @cDefine("UNICODE", {});
    @cDefine("_UNICODE", {});
    @cDefine("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN", {});
    @cInclude("windows.h");
});

However, when I try to build the above using zig build -Dtarget=x86_64-windows-msvc, I get the error:
src\main.zig:1:17: error: C import failed
            const windows = @cImport({
                            ^~~~~~~~
src\main.zig:1:17: note: libc headers not available; compilation does not link against libc

How can I @cInclude C headers without linking libc?

Caveat: I don't know zig ... But, it looks like the zig compiler is looking for C .h files for libc: libc headers not available. This doesn't necessarily mean that the object will try to link to libc symbols. So, can you get it so it can find some headers (e.g. stdio.h) for whatever .h files it is using to probe. I don't know what the windows equivalent of strace is, but I'd run it on the zig command to see what files it is searching for.

I'm confused. You use target x86_64-windows-msvc but then you mention MinGW. For MinGW-w64 you should use target x86_64-w64-mingw32.

@BrechtSanders I apologize for my miscommunication. I meant that I'm certain MSVC doesn't rely on libc (headers or otherwise) but I'm not sure whether or not MinGW does in any capacity, so I opted for explicity targeting MSVC (instead of Zig's default of MinGW for Windows) to ensure that it wasn't the target that was causing my issue.

There is no libc for native Windows. Essentially MinGW-w64 is a libc replacement for Windows. A lot of the time people refer to MinGW-w64 while they actually mean build tools like GCC and binutils (or even LLVM) tagetting Windows using the MinGW-w64 as underlying library.

@BrechtSanders I apologize again for my imprecision. When I said "MinGW" I meant Zig's MinGW-based backend (-Dtarget=x86_64-windows-gnu) not the actual project itself. My concern with using this target was that the MinGW-w64 Windows.h (included in your build on winlibs and (I think) used by Zig) may refer to the MinGW-w64's libc headers, causing the "libc headers not available" error. I therefore used the MSVC backend to ensure that something else is going wrong besides a (potentially) trivial libc dependency error.

I edited my question, removing any confusing reasoning.
